# Please explain updatable = false in the reference to JPA @Column on IDENTITY generator column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Can some one show the light on what is the impact of `updatable = false` on `IDENTITY` generator column for oracle database?

```
@Id
@Column(updatable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Comment: Did you read the official documentation about that: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#updatable() - if yes, what part of that description do you require clarification about?

Comment: I have read about it and understood "updatable = false" will ignore the column during update and here it is given on non primary key field.. Just want to understand the same on primary key field and the impact if any? I am facing some performance issues during saveAll() with IDENETITY generator for entities that has one to many relations and so wanted to reduce the fetch calls during update and need to understand its impact of updatable = false on primary key column

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation that i linked about different behaviors on primary/non primary key columns. So I'd assume it just acts exactly the same and just makes sure the column is not included in update statements.

Comment: It is unnecessary as ID columns are immutable in JPA. Providers may want to allow changing the values, but most will complain and throw exceptions as changing identity breaks entity caching.

Comment: You are right @Chris.. setting updatable = false on primary key doesn't improve performance.. any suggestions on how to improve performance with IDENTITY generator on oracle db.. will IDENTITY generator not consider the batch updates ? (already this update hibernate property is set to true in properties file)

Comment: Identity assigns the ID when the Insert statement is executed, which means providers have to get back the value from the statement. How it does that depends on the database, drivers and its support; IDK if hibernate can handle this when issuing batch inserts, if it has implemented how to figure out the return ID value for each row in that single statement. You will have to check the SQL logs and behavior, and the docs. I know EclipseLInk can support it, but I still steer toward other generation strategies so they are set on the persist calls upfront and don't rely on DB interactions.